# merge st_voronoi polygons by variable

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, r-sf, voronoi

I'd like to create polygons with st_voronoi and merge them by a variable

```
library(sf)
nc_centroids <- st_transform(nc_centroids,crs=32119)
nc_centroids$foo <- c(rep("green",50),rep("red",50))
nc <- st_transform(nc,crs=32119)
v <- st_voronoi(st_union(nc_centroids))
plot(v, col = 0)
plot(st_intersection(st_cast(v), st_union(nc)), col = 0) 
plot(nc_centroids, add = TRUE)
```

How might I merge the polygons in v by nc_centroids$foo to create two big polygons? I can think of some hacks, like using lapply to join the individual polygons of v, e.g., (v[[1]][[x]]). But surely there's something easier

Comment: For merging of polygons (any polygons, including, but not limited to, voronoi polygons) consider using `dplyr::summarise()` - you will find it explained in more detail than can fit here in https://www.jla-data.net/eng/merging-geometry-of-sf-objects-in-r/ - just remember that the output of `sf::st_voronoi()` is a plain geometry object, i.e. it requires a conversion from sfc to sf object to be able to hold any data (including the variables for dissolving)

Comment: How would I transform v to get at the polygons? st_sf() doesn't do it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please find below a reprex that details one possible approach.

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc_centroids <- st_centroid(nc)
nc_centroids <- st_transform(nc_centroids,crs=32119)
nc_centroids$foo <- c(rep("green",50),rep("red",50))
nc <- st_transform(nc,crs=32119)
v <- st_voronoi(st_union(nc_centroids))


v <- v %>% 
  st_collection_extract(., "POLYGON") %>% 
  st_as_sf()

v_result <- v %>% 
  st_join(., nc_centroids, st_intersects) %>% 
  group_by(foo) %>% 
  summarize()

nc_result <- nc %>% 
  st_join(., v_result) %>% 
  group_by(foo) %>% 
  summarize()
```

- Output

```r
plot(nc_result)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: st_collection_extract() was what I needed! I just reposted my comment so your answer makes more sense to others

Comment: You are welcome. Glad that I could help. Cheers.

Comment: Poking around I don't see st_collection_extract() explained in any tutorial . . . some aspects of sf really are mysteries!